# PHP inside Wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, embed, shortcode

I've done a ton of searching and I'm pulling out what's left of my hair. The PHP code on its own is:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($file->ID) ?>
```

...the shortcode is: `[embed][/embed]`

I've tried all sorts of variations of 'do shortcode' but can't get things working. Can you suggest the correct code?

Comment: I've just tried this and nothing is generated: `                  <?php
$mp3 = wp_get_attachment_url($file->ID);
echo do_shortcode('[embed]'.$mp3.'[/embed]');
?>`

Answer (score 0):

WordPress (3.6 or higher) has an `audio` shortcode, the following should work:

```
$mp3 = wp_get_attachment_url( $file->ID );
echo do_shortcode( '[audio src="' . $mp3 . '"]' );
```

More info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Audio_Shortcode

Comment: Thanks diggy. However, it still outputs nothing. `<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($file->ID) ?>` on its own outputs the mp3 URL as it should though.

Comment: very weird, tested the code on a local installation, and it works fine

Comment: Can you confirm that other shortcodes are working? If not, maybe your theme or some plugin is stripping them (see `strip_shortcodes` for example).

Comment: I've found out the issue - it should have been "audio file=" and not "audio src="... all working now. Thanks for giving me a good starting point!

Comment: The "audio file=" workaround is this theme's own player. In other news, I've commented out all strip_shortcodes (there were two instances in the entire theme files) but they were referencing the_excerpt so that didn't seem to work. There seems to be a something stripping shortcodes for this section of the site. The search goes on!